# Private network with static node using geth client

Tags: ethereum

I want to set up a private ethereum network using geth by using static-nodes.json file.
I have created the static nodes.json file with 4 enodes and put it in the 
/usr/local/cellar/test2/geth/ static-nodes.json.
In Geth console I encountered an error 
`ERROR[11-06|10:11:33] Can't load node file /usr/local/Cellar/test2/geth/static-nodes.json: JSON syntax error at /usr/local/Cellar/test2/geth/static-nodes.json:4: invalid character '\n'` in string literal. Can someone guide how to set up the permanent nodes private ethereum network .
***static node.json file***

```
[
"enode://dc3e4f23315f90bb62c9096df01b7f07c4040a8520f046801e2fa6812aa4402d70f6073f6226779a9183137cb789e98492d197db1380784fd0d213c30e9651ec@192.168.1.139:30331",
"enode://1c745b2459129ca07b1345487fedda6b8516194a4208d93bd696f3684b44cbf16a5cdddb99cc1753b1ba43884d93c5d27403dce0c6638787f74a40428a7c9543@192.168.1.117:30332”,
"enode://be0c22a7a8451766c2894cd11143bc3128d5840cca161ad91b2bd9078d1dde56ddc19d0258e86e51cf7b7e9cda43b900a20ef392925ae8a19ab24c4cf016d69c@192.168.1.121:30333”,
"enode://1e07a29f0c94617d045dcf4f0d8597fd07757cbf8e48f66e78b72b142bf9b61d0d7bcce8fe21479ad0bd02bff945a8c062f2af03c0e1be670e1452b845fa420e@192.168.1.102:30334"
]
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all spaces and line-breaks? Sounds like a bug on Geth side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an invalid double-quote in your JSON file: `”` vs. `"`.

I used the [JSON formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to find that out. Here is the corrected version:

```
[
  "enode://dc3e4f23315f90bb62c9096df01b7f07c4040a8520f046801e2fa6812aa4402d70f6073f6226779a9183137cb789e98492d197db1380784fd0d213c30e9651ec@192.168.1.139:30331",
  "enode://1c745b2459129ca07b1345487fedda6b8516194a4208d93bd696f3684b44cbf16a5cdddb99cc1753b1ba43884d93c5d27403dce0c6638787f74a40428a7c9543@192.168.1.117:30332",
  "enode://be0c22a7a8451766c2894cd11143bc3128d5840cca161ad91b2bd9078d1dde56ddc19d0258e86e51cf7b7e9cda43b900a20ef392925ae8a19ab24c4cf016d69c@192.168.1.121:30333",
  "enode://1e07a29f0c94617d045dcf4f0d8597fd07757cbf8e48f66e78b72b142bf9b61d0d7bcce8fe21479ad0bd02bff945a8c062f2af03c0e1be670e1452b845fa420e@192.168.1.102:30334"
]
```